# Proper way of setting up one DNS server for multiple domains

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a dillema about what would be the proper way to setup one DNS as master server for two or more domains? For example, if I have two domains: *first.com* and *second.com*, and one DNS server with public IP address. 
Should I setup in this manner:

zone file for *first.com*

```
$ORIGIN first.com.
@       IN     SOA   ns1.first.com. hostmaster.first.com. (
               2003080800 ; serial number
               3h         ; refresh =  3 hours 
               15M        ; update retry = 15 minutes
               3W12h      ; expiry = 3 weeks + 12 hours
               2h20M      ; minimum = 2 hours + 20 minutes
               )
              IN      NS     ns1.first.
              IN      NS     ns2.first.

ns1           IN      A      70.0.0.3 # address for example purposes
ns2           IN      A      70.0.0.4 #
```

zone file for *second.com*:

```
$ORIGIN second.com.
@       IN     SOA   ns1.second.com. hostmaster.second.com. (
               2003080800 ; serial number
               3h         ; refresh =  3 hours 
               15M        ; update retry = 15 minutes
               3W12h      ; expiry = 3 weeks + 12 hours
               2h20M      ; minimum = 2 hours + 20 minutes
               )
              IN      NS     ns1.second.
              IN      NS     ns2.second.

ns1           IN      A      70.0.0.3 # address for example purposes
ns2           IN      A      70.0.0.4 #
```

and in the parent zone create four NS records and four glue A records:

```
first         IN      NS     ns1.first.com.
              IN      NS     ns2.first.com.

second        IN      NS     ns1.second.com.
              IN      NS     ns2.second.com.

ns1.first     IN      A      70.0.0.3
ns2.first     IN      A      70.0.0.4

ns1.second    IN      A      70.0.0.3
ns2.second    IN      A      70.0.0.4
```

Or should it be configured so that in *second.com* we define ns1.first. as master name server, and two NS records for *ns1.first.com.* and *ns2.first.com.* without A records for those? Like this:

```
$ORIGIN second.com.
@       IN     SOA   ns1.first.com. hostmaster.second.com. (
                   2003080800 ; serial number
                   3h         ; refresh =  3 hours 
                   15M        ; update retry = 15 minutes
                   3W12h      ; expiry = 3 weeks + 12 hours
                   2h20M      ; minimum = 2 hours + 20 minutes
                   )
                  IN      NS     ns1.first.
                  IN      NS     ns2.first.
```

In that case, in parent zone we would define four NS records and two A glue records:

```
first         IN      NS     ns1.first.com.
              IN      NS     ns2.first.com.

second        IN      NS     ns1.first.com.
              IN      NS     ns2.first.com.

ns1.first     IN      A      70.0.0.3
ns2.first     IN      A      70.0.0.4
```

*ns2* is the name server configured as slave server for both domains, also with public IP address.

My appologies if question is trivial, but after reading substantial amount of text and thinking about it I'm still not sure about what is correct way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `bind9` for your DNS server?

Comment: @2ps yes, I'm using 'bind9'.

Answer (score 4):

I think that typically as a nameserver operator you would want to decide once and for all what the names of your nameservers are and then use those names for any number of zones that you host.

Your nameservers could be named something customer/purpose neutral like  `ns1.hostingcompany.example`, `ns2.hostingcompany.example`, `ns3.hostingcompany.example`, `ns4.hostingcompany.example`.

It is possible to refer to the same nameservers by multiple names, but that will tend to result in glue records for many domains (maybe outside of your control?), effectively making it harder for you to maintain your own environment.

Answer (score 0):

When configuring a single DNS server you usually set up separate zones for each domain, making sure to create both forward and reverse zone files for all domains that you are configuring a particular name server for.  The configuration you use will be very specific to the DNS server that you are using, and it was not clear from your post what server you were using.  A popular DNS server on linux environments is bind9.  To configure multiple domains with bind9, here is what you should do:

`/etc/named.conf`:

```
zone "first.com" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/named/zones/db.first.com";
};

zone "second.com" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/named/zones/db.second.com";
};
```

in `/etc/named/zones/db.first.com`:

```
$ORIGIN first.com.
@       IN     SOA   ns1.first.com. hostmaster.first.com. (
               2003080800 ; serial number
               3h         ; refresh =  3 hours 
               15M        ; update retry = 15 minutes
               3W12h      ; expiry = 3 weeks + 12 hours
               2h20M      ; minimum = 2 hours + 20 minutes
               )
              IN      NS     ns1.first.com.
              IN      NS     ns2.first.com.

ns1.first.com.           IN      A      70.0.0.3 # address for example purposes
ns2.first.com.           IN      A      70.0.0.4 #
```

And in `/etc/named/zones/db.second.com`:

```
$ORIGIN second.com.
@       IN     SOA   ns1.second.com. hostmaster.second.com. (
               2003080800 ; serial number
               3h         ; refresh =  3 hours 
               15M        ; update retry = 15 minutes
               3W12h      ; expiry = 3 weeks + 12 hours
               2h20M      ; minimum = 2 hours + 20 minutes
               )
              IN      NS     ns1.second.com.
              IN      NS     ns2.second.com.

ns1.second.com.           IN      A      70.0.0.3 # address for example purposes
ns2.second.com.           IN      A      70.0.0.4 #
```

And then you can configure 70.0.0.4 (or `ns2`) as a slave making sure to `allow-transfers` and specifying the ns1 address in the `masters`.

No glue records needed from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this would be the right way of doing it:

*first* zone file

```
$ORIGIN first.com.
@       IN     SOA   ns1.first.com. hostmaster.first.com. (
               2003080800 ; serial number
               3h         ; refresh =  3 hours 
               15M        ; update retry = 15 minutes
               3W12h      ; expiry = 3 weeks + 12 hours
               2h20M      ; minimum = 2 hours + 20 minutes
               )
              IN      NS     ns1.first.com.
              IN      NS     ns2.first.com.

ns1           IN      A      70.0.0.3 # address for example purposes
ns2           IN      A      70.0.0.4 #
```

*second* zone file

```
$ORIGIN second.com.
@       IN     SOA   ns1.second.com. hostmaster.first.com. (
               2003080800 ; serial number
               3h         ; refresh =  3 hours 
               15M        ; update retry = 15 minutes
               3W12h      ; expiry = 3 weeks + 12 hours
               2h20M      ; minimum = 2 hours + 20 minutes
               )
              IN      NS     ns1.first.com.
              IN      NS     ns2.first.com.

ns1.first.com.           IN      A      70.0.0.3 # example address
ns2.first.com.           IN      A      70.0.0.4 #
```

*parent* zone file

```
first         IN      NS     ns1.first.com.
              IN      NS     ns2.first.com.

second        IN      NS     ns1.first.com.
              IN      NS     ns2.first.com.

ns1.first     IN      A      70.0.0.3
ns2.first     IN      A      70.0.0.4
```